# Git: Get updates from repository

Tags: git, repository, commit

I'm new to Git and after testing and researching how it works there is one question that still is not very clear for me.

I'm gonna use a practical example to better illustrate my question: Let's say I work in a team and have a project folder named my_project and I have 3 files inside it (file-A, file-B and file-C).

I make some changes to file-A and commit to the repository and another team member also makes some changes to that same file and commit the changes to the repository as well.

My question is: How can I get the changes made by my team member in order to update my file-A with his changes?

Could someone please clarify how that process works?

Thank you.
Looking forward to hear your thoughts.

Comment: One person pushes to the remote repo (eg, GitHub) and the other person puls.

Comment: You do a Git fetch or pull.  Please read a decent Git tutorial (e.g. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial or http://git-scm.com/book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git keeps a history of all changes to all files on your local computer.  If you want to share changes between team members, you have a few options.

**Use a remote repository**

With this option, you and your teammates would setup a repository on a site like [Github](https://github.com) or [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com).  If you're worried about your code being open to the public, you can always setup a local instance of Gitlab inside your network.  Your remotes would look like:

```
$ git remote
github
```

With this method, each team member would setup a remote to the Github repository and then push their changes to Github while the other teammates would pull down the changes.  Your workflow would look something like:

```
Hack on the files
$ git pull github
Fix any merge problems
$ git push github
```

**Use a push/pull directly from team members**

In this method, you would add a remote for each of your teammates computers.  Your remotes would look like:

```
$ git remote
jane
paul
olivia
magikid
```

There would be no central repository and your workflow would look something like:

```
Hack on files
$ git pull jane // to get her changes
$ git pull paul // to pull in his changes
$ git pull olivia // grab her changes
$ git pull magikid // grab his changes
```

The big difference here is that there is no central repository of all the changes.  Each team member would have all of the changes that they had pulled on their computer.

Comment: @brunodd Accepting **and upvoting** answers is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Jubobs: brunodd doesn't have the rep to upvote yet.

Comment: @magikid Arf... my mistake. I'll do it for him.

Comment: @magikid No problem, although I would personally recommend breaking `pull` into `fetch` + `merge` or `fetch` + `rebase`.

Comment: That is how I would personally do it but since he mentioned that he was new to Git, I didn't want to scare him off with a discussion of  merge vs rebase.

Comment: Thank you guys. It doesn't seems that hard. I'm getting used with the commands as I never worked with command line before.